# enlarge font size according to the div height

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am applying text watermark on to multiples images and i want to display scaling of text.I am enlarge `font-size` according to the div by enlarging the div as well as text into them
this is what i am doing [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/fRq2J/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //vertically enlarge div and font-size     
    $('#vertically').on('change', function() {
        ScaValue = this.value;
        OriginalHeight = $("#backgroundImg").height();
        var newHeightofDiv  = (OriginalHeight/100) * ScaValue;
        fontsize = newHeightofDiv/10;
        $("#dragable").css({"width":"auto","height":newHeightofDiv,"font-size":fontsize});
  });


        //horizontally enlarge div and font-size 
    $('#horizontally').on('change', function() {
        ScaValue = this.value;
        Originalwidth = $("#backgroundImg").width();
        var newWidthofDiv  = (Originalwidth/100) * ScaValue;
        fontsize = newWidthofDiv/10;
        $("#dragable").css({"width":newWidthofDiv,"height":"auto","font-size":fontsize});
  });


});
```

The above code work fine in case of Horizontally Scaling but not get exact scaling in case of vertical Scaling. Please Point me in right direction

Comment: Why don't you use `font-size:10%` in css?

Comment: Or use `em`, which scales to `line-height` automatically.

Comment: i tried both `font-size:10%` and `em` but still not get correct values

Comment: maybe use same ID on the same object

Comment: it seems `backgroundImg` `width` double than `height`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery resize plugin to invoke the div resize event. You will get this plugin from the following link

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

I am checking the scale of height change by subtracting the currentHeight from the previous height. For doing this I removed the 'px' value from the height argument. Then if it's a increase in size then I will increase the font size in similar ratio according to the rate of change of height, otherwise I will decrease the font size.

But there was some problems while doing this. When I changed the font-size it was resizing the div also, so it again called the resize event and it became an infinite loop. So I used one boolean variable named resi(short for resize), and when font resize is done I setted it to true, so next time when I invoke the resize method it will skip the execution of the function

```
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="mydiv" style="min-height:300px;font-size:23px;border:solid 2px black;">
         Hai I am Akhil
         <div id="inner" style='height:200px;border:solid 2px red;'></div> 
         </div>
      </div>
     <input type="button" id="check" value="Increase"/>
     <input type="button" id="down" value="Decrease"/>
     <script  src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
     <script  src="jquery-resize.js"></script>
     <script>
       var height=$("#mydiv").css("height");
       height=height.substring(0,(height.length-2));
       var font=$("#mydiv").css("font-size");
       var resi=false;
       $("#mydiv").resize(function(){
            if(resi){
                 var currentHeight=$("#mydiv").css("height");
                 currentHeight= currentHeight.substring(0,(currentHeight.length-2));
                 var change=currentHeight-height;
                 height=currentHeight;
                 if(change>0){
                var currentFont=$("#mydiv").css("font-size");
                font=currentFont;
                      currentFont= currentFont.substring(0,(currentFont.length-2));
                $("#mydiv").css("font-size", ((currentFont*(change/100))+"px"));
                      resi=false;
                 }else if(change<0){
                change=change*-1;
                var currentFont=$("#mydiv").css("font-size");
                font=currentFont;
                      currentFont= currentFont.substring(0,(currentFont.length-2));
                $("#mydiv").css("font-size", ((currentFont/(change/100))+"px"));
                      resi=false;
                 }
              }
           });
          $("#check").click(function(){
                 $("#inner").css("height","600px");
                 resi=true;
          });
         $("#down").click(function(){
               $("#inner").css("height","400px");
               resi=true;
          });
       </script>
       </html>
```

I have given 2 buttons to increase and decrease the size of the div.
 If u have any doubt u can ask.